# How do I split the string to variables

Tags: python

I have this type of strings.

```
data = [{'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''},
        {'value': 'Bond', 'footnoteid': 'F2, F3'},
        {'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''},
        {'value': 'Option', 'footnoteid': 'F4'}]
```

I want this to be two sets of variables.

```
 obs | value        | footnoteid
-----+--------------+------------
 1   | Common Stock |
 2   | Bond         | F2, F3
 3   | Common Stock |
 4   | Option       | F4
```

The code I tried is this.

```
value=data.get['value']
list_value=reverse.value

footnote=data.get['footnote']
list_footnote=reverse.footnote
```

I don't see a proper result coming from my code.

Comment: it is list with dictionares so you need `data[0].get('value')` `data[0].get('footnoteid')`, `data[1].get('value')` `data[1].get('footnoteid')`, etc OR use `for` loop.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What does "two sets of variables" mean? What form do you want the output data to be in? Are you looking to transform the `data` object into another Python data structure, or are you just looking to print a report? And what's `reverse` in the code you show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is list with dictionares so use

```
data = [{'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': 'Bond', 'footnoteid': 'F2, F3'}, {'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': 'Option', 'footnoteid': 'F4'}]

print( data[0].get('value'), data[0].get('footnoteid') )
print( data[1].get('value'), data[1].get('footnoteid') )
```

or use `for` loop

```
data = [{'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': 'Bond', 'footnoteid': 'F2, F3'}, {'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': 'Option', 'footnoteid': 'F4'}]

for item in data:
    print(item.get('value'), item.get('footnoteid'))
```

To get numbers you can add `enumerate()`

```
for number, item in enumerate(data, 1):
    print(number, item.get('value'), item.get('footnoteid'))
```

---

BTW: You could also use it directly with `pandas` to create `DataFrame` which can be useful.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': 'Bond', 'footnoteid': 'F2, F3'}, {'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': 'Option', 'footnoteid': 'F4'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

DataFrame

```
   footnoteid         value
0             Common Stock
1     F2, F3          Bond
2             Common Stock
3         F4        Option
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using `dictionary comprehension`

```
>>> data = [{'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': 'Bond', 'footnoteid': 'F2, F3'}, {'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': 'Option', 'footnoteid': 'F4'}]
>>> result = {index:val['value']+' '+val['footnoteid'] for index,val in enumerate(data)}
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> print(result)
{
 0: 'Common Stock ', 
 1: 'Bond F2, F3', 
 2: 'Common Stock ', 
 3: 'Option F4'
 }
```

**After OP new edit:**

You can use pandas, as shown below to acheive new expected output:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> print(df)
  footnoteid         value
0             Common Stock
1     F2, F3          Bond
2             Common Stock
3         F4        Option
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` with a list comprehension:

```
list_value, list_footnote = zip(*[[x['value'], x['footnoteid']] for x in data])
```

**Example**:

```
data = [{'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': 'Bond', 'footnoteid': 'F2, F3'}, {'value': 'Common Stock', 'footnoteid': ''}, {'value': 'Option', 'footnoteid': 'F4'}]

list_value, list_footnote = zip(*[[x['value'], x['footnoteid']] for x in data])

print(list_value)     # ('Common Stock', 'Bond', 'Common Stock', 'Option') 
print(list_footnote)  # ('', 'F2, F3', '', 'F4')
```